# Resize the image according to the window size without having to refresh the page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I got the following code below which resizes the image depending on window size. My code only works when you resize then refresh the screen to see the changes. How do i make the image visible or hidden depending on the screen size without having to refresh the screen to see the changes to the image? Is there a better way to do it?

**JQuery**

```
<script>
    if ($(window).width() < 950) {
       $('body').addClass('imgHide');
        console.log($(window).width());
    }
    else { 
       $('body').addClass('imgShow');
    }
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
.imgHide #DuckImg
{
    visibility: hidden;     
}

.imgShow #DuckImg
{
    visibility: visible;
}
```

**My Image**

```
<img id="DuckImg" class="DuckImg" src="DuckImg.png" alt="DuckImg"  >
```

Comment: you don't using a wrap for your image? it will be easier if you got some, like div or section.

Comment: Should i wrap my image in a div section? @Obink

Comment: depends, what exactly your works like. in my opinion, if you resize the div it would be easier and you won't bother with the image width.

Comment: Is [this](http://ciphertext.info/software/dyphal/#/demo/1) more or less the effect that you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with pure CSS using [Media Queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp) and with jQuery using the window resize event (you can also do it by using pure javascript, but you do use jQuery in your example code).

**CSS Way**

---

**CSS**

```
.DuckImg {
    visibility: visible;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 949px) {
    .DuckImg {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<img id="DuckImg" class="DuckImg" src="http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/duck/duck-07.jpg" alt="DuckImg">
```

My CSS example page: http://zikro.gr/dbg/html/imgSize/css.html

**jQuery Way**

---

**CSS**

```
.DuckImg {
    visibility: visible;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
jQuery(function($) {

    function doresize() {
        if($(document).width() < 950)
            $('#DuckImg').hide();
        else    
            $('#DuckImg').show();
    }

    $(window).on('resize', doresize);
    doresize();

});
```

**HTML**

```
<img id="DuckImg" class="DuckImg" src="http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/duck/duck-07.jpg" alt="DuckImg">
```

My jQuery example page: http://zikro.gr/dbg/html/imgSize/jquery.html

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the image properties when the window is resized, you'll need to register a handler for an appropriate resize event.  For instance (in JavaScript; I don't know jquery):

```
window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize, false);
```

where `handleResize' is a function containing your code.  Also, I'm not sure what will happen if you have "visibility: hidden" and "visibility: visible" set on the same object; you'll probably want to somehow toggle between the two classes rather than just appending a new one every time your handler gets called.

For an example that may do roughly what you want, take a look at the function `fitPhoto` in https://github.com/rdegraaf/dyphal/blob/master/www/dyphal.js#L309.

Comment: I could try resizing the image in JavaScript. I'm not limited to JQuery, I'll give your method a shot.